# How is this question a proper candidate for a close vote audit?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I failed an audit on close votes queue for the following question: [Finding minimal subset of columns that make rows in a matrix unique](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36449631/1461424)

Even though it's tagged with [optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optimization) the question does not have any code. The question basically asks for an algorithm to solve a problem. Therefore I flagged it as *too broad*, and failed the audit.

What have I missed? How is this a good candidate for a positive close vote audit?

Answer (score 4):

The system has two types of audits "known bad" and "know good".  The only way to automate that is to use certain criteria like votes, close votes, answers, attention.  With "know good" audits A question needs to be at least +5 and have no down votes and no close votes(may be others but I think the whole thing is secret).

If we look at the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36449631/timeline) we can see that it got 5 votes on its first day so that looks promising and we can see from the post that there are no down votes.  We can also see that a close vote since it takes 14 days to age away and the question has not been on SO for that long.  So it was positively received and no one disliked it so it must be good.  That is about as far as the system can go.

If you feel like it is not good enough for an audit you can always vote to close or give it a down vote which should remove it as an audit candidate.  As it stands right now though it is being used as an audit in the close vote queue and the reopen vote queue and 2 other users both passed audits when it was displayed.

I personally would not vote to close it but I also wouldn't up vote it.